# Projects & going up in directories

Tags: r, directory, project

I am working on an R project, this project works on OneDrive and it looks like this:

Economy >

- Scraping (here is my .Rproj)
- GDP > Indicators > Information > Information Received

I want to access inside my .RProj files in Information Received, of course I can this way:

```
auxiliar_path <- "C:/Users/MyName/CompanyName/Economy/GDP/Indicators/Information/Information Received"
```

As this is a collaborative project I do not want to specify in the directory my name, just go upwards, I've tried with here but I could not find a way.

Comment: Why not include the directories you are trying to access as a subdirectory in your R project? Then you could use a relative path like `"GDP/Indicators/..."` since the default working directory for the project is the project directory. I've never worked with OneDrive before, but I would think collaboration would be easier through something like GitHub. Then your collaborators could clone the repo to work on it, and code changes would be tracked.

Comment: @cazman I am the only one who really understands R, so imposing git would be a dream but it is not achievable (I use it but for myself). 
I thought about that but others use this directory for other things, so I would be duplicating the folder.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the overarching situation here: on your computer you have a project, and you want your colleagues to be able to use the code without using absolute path names. @cazman's suggestion to use *relative* paths makes sense to me, it would only require that your project is working in a known location such as `"C:/Users/MyName/CompanyName/Economy/"`; if a colleague is using R and has your code mirrored somehow, why can they not do the same?

Comment: `..` means "up one level", so if you are in `Scrapping`, then `..` is `Economy`. You should be able to use `../GDP/Indicators/Information/Information Received`.

Comment: You may also want to correct the common typo "scrapping" -> "scraping".

Comment: Thanks for the typo advice! When using list.files("../GDP/Indicators/Information/Information Received") is empty, whereas using list.files("C:/Users/MyName/CompanyName/Economy/GDP/Indicators/Information/Information Received") works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This worked fine!

```
auxiliar_path <- "../../GDP/Indicators/Information/Information Received"
```

Thanks everyone!